# Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, ioexception

`Server.java`

```
public class Server {
    public static BufferedReader inFromClient = null;
    public static DataOutputStream outToClient = null;
    public static Socket connectionSocket = null;
    static ServerSocket welcomeSocket = null;
    static String path = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        welcomeSocket = new ServerSocket(1001);

        FileInputStream fin = null;
        FileOutputStream fout = null;

        while (true) {

            connectionSocket = welcomeSocket.accept();

            inFromClient = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                    connectionSocket.getInputStream()));

            outToClient = new DataOutputStream(
                    connectionSocket.getOutputStream());
            path = inFromClient.readLine();

            if (path != null) {
                String fileName = new File(path).getName();

                File file = new File(path);
                File file2 = new File(fileName);

                fin = new FileInputStream(file);

                fout = new FileOutputStream(file2);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
                int bytesRead;
                while ((bytesRead = fin.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                    fout.write(buffer, 0, bytesRead);
                }

                fin.close();
                fout.close();
            }

        }
    }
}
```

I'm getting this error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
    at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
    at Server.main(Server.java:37)
```

And here is what I was trying to do.

After I run the Server.java and then run Client.java. I tried by press the Choose button, but didn't choose any file and then close the File Chooser after that.

In my understanding is that this line

```
  path = inFromClient.readLine();
```

When it tries to readLine, but didn't find anything which is why it says unknown source, but how do I fix this?

In my `Client.java` I'm trying to `close()` the socket but its not close at all....

UPDATE I have fixed the error by putting try&catch on the server.java where the error occur, and that fixed the problem!

Comment: `try/catch` doesn't fix anything. It changes the behaviour.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> When it tries to readLine, but didn't find anything which is why it says unknown source

No it isn't. That refers to the fact that the source code concerned wasn't compiled with debug information so the source line number and file weren't available when the stack trace was printed.

The most common explanation of this condition is that you have written to a connection that has already been closed by the peer: in other words, an application protocol error.

Why are you writing a server whose function is to copy a file from one location to another based on an input from the client?